# Der Unterschied zwischen besorgen und bekommen

Tags: verb, verb-usage, verb-choice

> *Ich besorge ihm die Zeitung.*
>
> *Ich bekomme ihm die Zeitung.*

Haben sie dieselbe Bedeutung wie ***to get*** ? Ich möchte wissen, in welchem Zusammenhang sie austauschbar verwendet werden können und in dem anderen können sie es nicht sein.

Comment: Außerdem gibt es noch "besorgen" als saloppe Formulierung für jmd. zum sexuellen Höhepunkt bringen, "Ich habe es ihr besorgt", "ich habe es mir selbst besorgt". Funktioniert nicht mit bekommen.

Comment: @userunknown "Salopp" ist möglicherweise ein wenig salopp ausgedrückt. Der Duden würde "vulgär" sagen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Ich bekomme ihm die Zeitung

funktioniert leider **nicht** - Man braucht irgendeine Präposition, z.B. "von"

> Ich bekomme *von* ihm die Zeitung

funktioniert viel besser. Achtung: **ich** habe die Zeitung am Ende, er hat sie mir gegeben. Soll **Er** am Ende die Zeitung haben, sagt man

> Er bekommt **von mir** die Zeitung
>
> Ich besorge ihm die Zeitung

funktioniert und bedeutet "ich beschaffe die Zeitung und gebe sie ihm".

Beide Verben lassen sich irgendwie mit "to get" übersetzen, sind aber im Deutschen absolut nicht austauschbar:

"besorgen" heißt "go get" - Ich habe den aktiven Teil und *bringe/hole* das Objekt (also eher wie "to fetch")

"bekommen" heißt "receive" - Ich habe den passiven Teil, sitze da und *erhalte* das Objekt